# How to upload pdf files in Tomcat directory?

Tags: file, tomcat, jersey

I am using Jersey for my REST backend, and i am developing a pdf upload feature. I prepared HTML form and backend REST method to upload, but i am able to upload only in my PC drive (example, on path C:/uploaded). Is there a method to upload in a Tomcat directory outside my app? For example, under "webapps/my-files"?

I am using Jersey 2.3 with multipart library and Tomcat 8.5.37 if needed.

I read lots of toturials and other questions, but all of then use c:/uploadedFiles or similar as upload location, so my doubts are still there.

First place, I wrote my REST service:

```
@POST
    @Path("upload")
    @Consumes(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA)
    @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
    public String uploadFile (@FormDataParam("file") InputStream file, @FormDataParam("file") FormDataContentDisposition fileData) {
        String uploadPath = "C:\\uploaded" + fileData.getFileName();
        try {
            int read = 0;
            byte[] bytes = new byte[1024];
            OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(new File (uploadPath));
            while ((read = file.read(bytes)) != -1) {
                out.write(bytes, 0, read);
            }
            out.flush();
            out.close();
            return "Completed";
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            return ex.getMessage();
        }
    }
```

Then, i tried to call it from Postman with POST method and using a simple pdf file as request body, and it works.

But now I want to upload in a server folder and not in any C:/ drive location. I want to know, where should I put the directory on server? I tried under webapps/, is ok? And then, how can I set variable "uploadPath" correctly to upload in that directory?

Comment: You might have a look at Tomcat's temporary directory that you can get by reading CATALINA_TMPDIR property. Be careful if uploading to webapps directory, for security reasons, you don't want anyone to read someone else's files yes ?

Comment: yes right, i know that is not a good practice but i dont know how i can do :/ can you explain this tmp directory trick? if it is temporary, how files will become persistent?

Comment: The temp dir is not supposed to keep persistent files. You can otherwise use CATALINA_BASE property to find where is running your Tomcat, and create a subdirectory in it (other then bin conf webapps ..)

Comment: so you suggest me to put the directory outside /webapps in tomcat root directory?

Comment: and then, how can i set that string variable to get that directory? i am using this to get webapps/ path:  `@Context private ServletContext context; private String getWebappsPath() { return new File (context.getRealPath("")).getAbsoluteFile().getParent(); }` in my service. project is in webapps, so path is c:/tomcat/webapps/project, and that method returns me c/tomcat/webapps. i modified my service: `string uploadPath = getWebappsPath() + "\\uploadedFiles\\" + fileData.getFileName();`. On localhost it works, not sure on a real server

Comment: Yes, I suggest to store in another directory than the ones that Tomcat uses for itself. You need to read the CATALINA_BASE system property and use it to build the correct uploadPath variable. If you need to learn how to read a system property, it's time to have a look at tutorials.

Comment: i know how to read, but i knew that catalina_base was optional and needed only if there are more tomcat instances, so i didnt define it and  tomcat startup use the same of catalina_home for catalina_base too. is this a problem? can you link me or explain better how to build the path?

Comment: When you are running a standalone ( = no instances ), CATALINA_BASE = CATALINA_HOME. By default I think this is good to use CATALINA_BASE, then you won't change anything later if you change your installation.

Comment: `uploadPath = catalinabase + "\\uploaded\\ + fileData.getFileName()` should work

Comment: ok very nice, on localhost work. But on a real server? is still good?

Comment: sure it is, just check the user which is running Tomcat (or the service if it is installed as a service) has the write rights to the folder you will use to store the uploaded files.